# convergence of affinity propagation

Tags: python-2.7, cluster-analysis

In fact I want to generate an initial population of an evolutionary algorithm using the results of affinity propagation algorithm to resolve the problem of community detection in social network. So at each iteration of the algorithm I keep the result, finally I have N solutions, where N is the number of iterations.

The python code is as follow:

```
def affinity_propagation3(S, preference=None, convergence_iter=25, max_iter=200,
                     damping=0.5, copy=True, verbose=False,
                     return_n_iter=False):

S = as_float_array(S, copy=copy)
n_samples = S.shape[0]
L1=[]

if S.shape[0] != S.shape[1]:
    raise ValueError("S must be a square array (shape=%s)" % repr(S.shape))

if preference is None:
    preference = np.median(S)
if damping < 0.5 or damping >= 1:
    raise ValueError('damping must be >= 0.5 and < 1')

random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)

# Place preference on the diagonal of S
S.flat[::(n_samples + 1)] = preference

A = np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))
R = np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))  # Initialize messages
# Intermediate results
tmp = np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))

# Remove degeneracies
S += ((np.finfo(np.double).eps * S + np.finfo(np.double).tiny * 100) *
      random_state.randn(n_samples, n_samples))

# Execute parallel affinity propagation updates
e = np.zeros((n_samples, convergence_iter))

ind = np.arange(n_samples)

for it in range(max_iter):
    # tmp = A + S; compute responsibilities
    np.add(A, S, tmp)
    I = np.argmax(tmp, axis=1)
    Y = tmp[ind, I]  # np.max(A + S, axis=1)
    tmp[ind, I] = -np.inf
    Y2 = np.max(tmp, axis=1)

    # tmp = Rnew
    np.subtract(S, Y[:, None], tmp)
    tmp[ind, I] = S[ind, I] - Y2

    # Damping
    tmp *= 1 - damping
    R *= damping
    R += tmp

    # tmp = Rp; compute availabilities
    np.maximum(R, 0, tmp)
    tmp.flat[::n_samples + 1] = R.flat[::n_samples + 1]

    # tmp = -Anew
    tmp -= np.sum(tmp, axis=0)
    dA = np.diag(tmp).copy()
    tmp.clip(0, np.inf, tmp)
    tmp.flat[::n_samples + 1] = dA

    # Damping
    tmp *= 1 - damping
    A *= damping
    A -= tmp

    # Check for convergence
    E = (np.diag(A) + np.diag(R)) > 0
    e[:, it % convergence_iter] = E
    K = np.sum(E, axis=0)

    if it >= convergence_iter:
        se = np.sum(e, axis=1)
        unconverged = (np.sum((se == convergence_iter) + (se == 0))
                       != n_samples)
        if (not unconverged and (K > 0)) or (it == max_iter):
            if verbose:
                print("Converged after %d iterations." % it)
            break
    print "iteration",it
    I = np.where(np.diag(A + R) > 0)[0]
    K = I.size  # Identify exemplars
    if K > 0:
        c = np.argmax(S[:, I], axis=1)
        c[I] = np.arange(K)  # Identify clusters
        for k in range(K):
            ii = np.where(c == k)[0]
            j = np.argmax(np.sum(S[ii[:, np.newaxis], ii], axis=0))
            I[k] = ii[j]
        c = np.argmax(S[:, I], axis=1)
        c[I] = np.arange(K)
        labels = I[c]
        cluster_centers_indices = np.unique(labels)
        labels = np.searchsorted(cluster_centers_indices, labels)
        L1.append(labels)


if return_n_iter:
    return cluster_centers_indices, labels, it + 1
else:
    return L1
```

but my problem is: after a few iteration the code return the same results which decrease the diversity of the population.
the code is applied on "dolphins network"  https://networkdata.ics.uci.edu/data.php?id=6

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AP is supposed to converge, and convergence means it changes less and less.

No, this is not a good approach to generate an initial population for evolutionary algorithms, because they indeed must be expected to be very similar.

Comment: thanks for your response, but can you suggest me another approach

Comment: No idea. Try random sampling.